# Could a double-sided Commodore disk be written to be used as a "flippy" on a 1541, without requiring flipping on a 1571?

Tags: commodore-64, floppy-disk, commodore, floppy-drive, commodore-128

Although the 1571 is capable of reading and writing both sides of a disk, accesses to the second side using the second head will be performed with the drive spinning in opposite direction from how it would be read if inserted upside-down and accessed with the first head (only head on the 1541).  Conceptually, however, it would seem like it should be possible to write a disk which could be read in either direction, either by:

1. If one only needed to use about half the capacity of the second side, one could format the disk side with a mixture of forward-written and reverse-written sector headers.  Track 18, for examine, which would normally contain 17 sectors, could have eight reverse-written headers for sectors 0-7, followed by eight forward-written headers for sectors 0-7.  If the BAM for the "read as flippy" direction marked as "used" all of the sectors that didn't exist in that direction, inserting the disk as a flippy would simply make it appear as a normal disk that appeared full despite having less than 85K of stuff on it.  Presumably, to make the other side compatible with 1541 drives, it would be formatted as a normal 170K disk, so any data on the reverse would have to be accessed using track/sector accesses.
2. If one needed to use more of the capacity, one could write much of the data using a custom format that would precede each sector with a forward-written header and immediately follow it with a reverse-written one.  Reading a reverse-written sector would require different decoding logic from reading a forward-written one, but I don't think the drive electronics should care about whether the data is being read forward or backward.

Would such a thing have been possible?  Has anyone ever done it, either back in the day or in the "retro-computing era"?

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that even the 1571 only has 2K RAM, and you need to store the code that deals with all the clever modifications somewhere.

Comment: @dirkt: Reading or writing the forward and backward formats wouldn't really be terribly different from handling other custom formats such as those used by the Vorpal Disk Utility.  BTW, I was really bummed back in the day at the 1571's failure to include 8K of RAM, since 8Kx8 RAM chips were commonplace and even 32Kx8 chips were available, and since being able to buffer a track would have made it possible to improve performance enormously.  If code asks for track 4 sector 2, and after moving the head to track 4 the drive sees a header for track 4 sector 5, reading that sector...

Comment: ...would cost nothing if buffer space is available.  Pre-emptively reading an entire track any time code asks for a sector would slightly increase the time required for the operation, but if code ends up wanting two or more sectors from the track, it would be a net performance win.

Comment: Again: You'll have to write code that cannot re-use much of the ROM. GCR tables backward will be different. Writing an address header backward will be different. 2K is not a lot, and you still need some of that for buffers. Maybe it can be done in 2K, but it will be pretty tricky. Only way to find out is to actually sit down and actually write it ...

Comment: @dirkt: In Commodore's encoding, every quintuple is either symmetrical or else has a mirror-image counterpart.  Thus, from what I can tell, reading data backward and decoding it using the normal tables would yield a bit pattern from which the forward data could be determined by reversing the order of nybbles and then applying a lookup table; such things could be done on the C64/C128 if need be to avoid the need to have the drive do them.

Comment: @dirkt: Alternatively, I would think that a 1571 used with a C128 could use a simple function to blindly send raw disk data via the CIA's hardware serial port for 210ms, and then let the 2MHz 8510 handle the decoding.

Comment: As I said: it will be tricky. The only way to find out is to come up with enough tricks like yours, implement it, and see if it fits. Everything else is handwaving.

Comment: @dirkt: Well, part of my question was whether anyone had done it (to which the answer is apparently no), and part was whether there issues that would rigidly preclude it (e.g. if one drive head used a field oriented parallel to the track while the other used a field perpendicular to the track).  It sounds like the answer is that it would likely be possible, but nobody's done it.

Comment: @dirkt: Incidentally, my current experimentation is with Apple disk formats, which seem more convenient to play with since the drive logic is located in the main CPU, but Commodore is what I mostly used back in the day.

Comment: @dirkt: Incidentally, it's probably not worth a separate question, but I wonder why Commodore's hardware reads hardware bits in groups of eight rather than 5?  I would think hardware to read groups of five would have been just as simple as hardware to read groups of 7, but reading quintets would have facilitated easy on-the-fly decoding.

Comment: Thinking about it, you can probably separate the formatting (needs to write address fields backwards) from the actual reading and writing (only needs to read and write data backward and forward, can probably use ROM routines for address fields), so that should make it easier to keep in with 2K. And yes, I guess the answer is that nobody has done it, and that it would be possible, but I can't be definite for either. And yes, Apple disk formats are much more convenient - for the Apple the answer would be a definite "yes, it's possible". If there was a reason to do that.

Comment: @dirkt: For the Apple, it would be impossible for 5.25" disks because Apple never made a double-sided version of the Disk II, and I think the 3.5" drives for the Apple II series all used hardware decoding.

Comment: Exactly. If there was a reason to do that = if Apple would have made a double-sided version. Which it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just the drive spinning in the opposite direction; tracks are also offset by about 8 track widths between front and back to prevent both mechanical (squeezing the disk too hard) and electrical (interference) problems.

Foone recently talked about that on Twitter: https://twitter.com/foone/status/1267014860589555712

So even if you could solve the "reading backwards" issue by some clever reprogramming of the drive, 8 tracks on the reverse side would remain mechanically inaccessible.

Comment: Surely that makes things easier with respect to the only-use-half suggestion as you therefore don’t have to craft an eighteenth track that can be read in either direction?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve, really -- if you only want to divide the second side into two non-overlapping partitions, then yes, that makes it easier, and gives you some extra capacity. However, I don't see what you would achieve this way...

Comment: Re, "solve the 'reading backwards' issue," Could be somewhat of an engineering problem. I don't remember much about what "formatting" looks like on a disk or how it's used, but I don't imagine that the stock hardware would even recognize that the disk was formatted if it was spinning the wrong way.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: If the disk only had headers written in one direction, that would be correct, but the drive would be capable of writing headers in either direction.

Comment: @MichaelGraf: My design thought had been, among other things, to make it so that a game which would normally have a "boot side" and a "play side" wouldn't need to be flipped over when using a Commodore 128 and 1571 drive, but would still be playable on a 1541.  And for that purpose, having tracks that would be available on the 1541 but not 1571 and vice versa would be fine.

Comment: @supercat, Of course, but writing is not the issue. OP asked, "...how it would be _read_ if inserted upside-down...?" Presumably, this is asking about reading a track in the opposite direction from the way it was written.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: The drive could write headers or data either "forward" or "backward".  If a drive were to write the data for a block in reverse order, followed by the header, also written in reverse order, then flipping the disk over and reading it with the opposite head should yield a sector written in forward order.